# RestEASY Host header being overridden

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

We are running security checks on our REST services and noticed that if a `Host` header is set, it is overriding the original server/host which is causing our returned URLs to use that host instead of the server.

Using Fiddler I can re-create the problem since it takes into account `Host` headers unlike browsers. The request, as seen here has 3 `Host` headers (for testing purposes): http://i.imgur.com/zrQhLOV.png

Our response URLs are, consequently, using the `test2.com` host instead of the desired `localhost`.

We have a series of filters defined in our `web.xml` that modify the request, however the server listed in the requests are still pointing to the wrong host.

I tried implementing a [`PreProcessInterceptor`](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html/Interceptors.html#PreProcessInterceptors) thinking that I might be able to catch the request and modify the `Host` headers.  The interceptor is implemented like so:

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
@Precedence("HEADER_DECORATOR")
public class PreProcessContextInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor {

  HttpRequest request;

  @Override
  public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod method)
      throws Failure, WebApplicationException {
    this.request = request;
    return null;
  }
}
```

It is registered in the `web.xml` before all of the filters are declared:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
  <param-value>com.package.ws.PreProcessContextInterceptor</param-value>
</context-param>
```

However, the problem is that the interceptor gets hit after our first filter and the request still has the wrong host set.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue or which direction to look within RestEASY?

Is it possible JAX-RS is the one setting the final `Host` header or is this probably happening in RestEASY?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is to use a RequestFilter, also you can check the host value before going into your rest controler :

```
/**
 * Servlet Filter implementation class MyRequestFilter
 */
@WebFilter("/*")
public class MyRequestFilter implements Filter {

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public MyRequestFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }    

    /**
     * @see Filter#destroy()
     */
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
     */
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        assert request instanceof HttpServletRequest;

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String host = req.getHeader("host");
        System.err.println(host);

        // pass the request along the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#init(FilterConfig)
     */
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. We do have several filters in place already, and when I examine the incoming request the `serverName` field is already set to the incorrect host. Somewhere the request is taking the multiple host fields and setting it to the last one it appears.  The only difference between our filters and the example you posted is that we don't annotate it with `@WebFilter` -- but it looks like we do that in our `web.xml`

Comment: really strange, how your client call the service ? It is java code too ?

Comment: I think there is little a confusion: the request headers are set up by the client, so generally your web navigator in fact, i dont't thing so that the server modify the request headers, or maybe another part of your program ?

Comment: I think there may be too. In this case, the 'client' is Fiddler which we're using to duplicate the problem. Our requests aren't built with Java - we have a UI in front of it that is typically through the browser (which ignores host headers) .. However, running the security scans shows us that we're accepting the `Host` header as shown with Fiddler. The problem is, I can't figure out if RESTEasy allows us to catch that request before the headers are set.

Comment: a tips: build a unit integration Test (Junit is your Friend), who call the service with HttClient (apache) - set your own values - and you will see : first time you don't have cookie or session id and no host too - second time you have - the host, who is url of your server - and cookies with id session. If the host is something else, that the request provide from another domain, i will try your client

Comment: Personnaly, i like to work with portable application who are not dedicated to an Operating System, like JMetter ...

Comment: Be carefull, with browsers who don't have the host as a Referer, JavaScript Technologie work for one domain only, it could set some impatcs !

Comment: After turning your target in my mind i suggest: install Paros proxy (hacking tools, you can trap a request before it came on server, set the proxy in your tools. After check the checkbox trap, and all request will be present in the proxy with all the value of the request. it is the better way to be sure !